# How to debug an R package (with C code) in Emacs using GDB?

Tags: r, gdb, emacs23

I am currently writing an R package and using compiled C++ code through the `Rcpp` package in R (Rcpp makes the interaction of R and C++ code easier for a non-programmer like me, IMHO).

I want to debug a few errors in my C++ program using gdb. I have googled and found mainly a few resources on debugging R within emacs, [R-FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Should-I-run-R-from-within-Emacs_003f), a few mails [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/1436), and definitely the R's Writing R Extension Manual.

However, I am doing this for the first time, I could not go too far. Could anyone give me a few pointers on how to debug R packages (or extensions with C++/C code) within emacs. Specifically, I want to take advantages of using ESS with R and gdb with Emacs (as the R-FAQ talks about).

Please note, I am ok on how to use gdb using *only* C or C++ programs. But I could not translate this knowledge to using gdb with R and extensions.

Answer (score 7):

You can leverage your existing knowledge of debugging C++ programs by turning the problem into a pure C++ development and debugging task using RInside (a great companion to Rcpp).

Write a `main()` C++ function that creates an R instance using RInside, executes R code (or sources an R script) that sets up the test case, and then call the function under test from main(), e.g.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RInside.h>
#include "function_under_test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace Rcpp;

    RInside R(argc, argv);

    string evalstr = R"(
        a <- matrix(c(1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1), nrow = 3, ncol=3)
    )";
    R.parseEvalQ(evalstr);

    SEXP a = R["a"];

    R["b"] = function_under_test(a);

    evalstr = R"(
        print(b)
    )";
    R.parseEvalQ(evalstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Then proceed as usual when debugging a C++ program with gdb by setting breakpoints in `function_under_test()` etc.

This way you avoid switching between R and C++ development environments and having to re-install the R package.

Comment: @user39275: C++11 supports raw strings (indicated by the "extraneous" R), which are useful for encapsulating multi-line R statements. This avoids having to escape line breaks manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's not all that easy, unfortunately. You need to jump between ESS, gdb (ie gud in Emacs) and R.  The best description is probably still win Writing R Extensions, however there was a [recent thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.ess.general/4884) on the [ESS mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.ess.general) that discusses this too (and note that some replies came in outside the thread so do look at the mailing list archive too).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I was the newbie asking the question in the thread (question by Prof. Bates and answered by Prof. Maechler) you mentioned.  :-(.

Comment: My use is `R -d gdb` from the command line, then `r` to tell gdb to (r)un R, `library(pkg)` then ctrl-c to break into gdb, set breakpoints, etc., i.e., no emacs. Keeping symbol names and program logic in my head is challenging enough for me, without having to remember the emacs / ESS layer.

Comment: I think that's the approach that is in *Writing R Extensions*, isn't?

Comment: Also, I find it very helpful to build R without optimizations and with the -ggdb debugging flags (R extentions may suggest this, too). At the command prompt: CFLAGS="-ggdb" CXXFLAGS="-ggdb" FFLAGS="-ggdb" ./configure --enable-R-shlib