# How to use QtCreator instead of gdb to debug C++ code in an R package based on Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, gdb, qt-creator, rcpp

Context: I have used RStudio on Ubuntu 18.04 to create an hello world R package with C++ code using [Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp) like described here in [Rcpp Package Development](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio):

[Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Debugging-compiled-code) explains how I can start R with GDB attached for debugging via this shell command:

```
$ R -d gdb --vanilla
```

I want to use QtCreator instead of gdb to have debugging GUI, but this doesn't work (just opens a hex dump window and I cannot run R):

```
$ R -d qtcreator --vanilla
```

How can I use QtCreator for debugging?

**Edit 1:**

Attaching the QtCreator debugger to a running R session does not work:
If I start R, [get the process ID in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58657851) via `Sys.getpid()` and choose 
*Debug > Start Debugging > Attach to running application* I get an error:

[image]

**Edit 2:** The `ptrace` error is caused by [kernel hardening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274645) that allows only debugging of child processes. I could solve this (temporarily) via

```
sudo su -
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
exit
```

Still an open issue: The QtCreator debugger shows the assembly code (not the C/C++ code)

Comment: To my knowledge QtCreator is just an IDE for Qt, and not a debugger. I would assume that the `-d gdb` flag is necessary to create debugging information, regardless of the tool that is used to analyze the code. Not sure if  `ddd`, a lightweight GUI for the gnu dbg, works in combination with Rcpp.

Comment: I have already tried `R -d ddd --vanilla` + `run` in the ddd/gdb console but a strange `DDD: Selection` is popping up which I do not understand

Comment: @RHertel The qtcreator IDE has an integrated debugger as plugin: `qtcreator --help` shows `qtcreator -debug` as option but I don't know to pass this switch to qtcreator (instead of R). This doesnt work: `R -d qtcreator -debug --vanilla`

Comment: There are many such C++ IDEs (CodeBlocks, eclipse CDT...) which seem to contain a debugger, but in the end they are just invoking the standard debugger like gdb, unless specified otherwise. I suspect that this is also the case for QtCreator. https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html .

Comment: @RHertel Yes, gdb is quite often the heart of visual debuggers. All I want is a debugging GUI for R to work faster (I always forget the gdb command names)

Comment: Can you attach to a running process using QtCreator? That‘s what I am using with the gdb front end provided by Emacs.

Comment: @RalfStubner Is this a "one-liner" to start debugging with Emacs (long long time ago I have used this editor ;-)

Comment: It is not that simple. I might be able to add it asan answer later.

Comment: @RalfStubner THX - I have just found a question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4980595

Answer (score 2):

Here the steps it takes me to do this using the gdb front end provided by Emacs. As an example, I am debugging a package that uses Rcpp:

1. Open the root directory of the package in Emacs.
2. Start an R session with ESS via `M-x R`.
3. Get the pid of the R session with `Sys.getpid()`.
4. Start gdb front end with `M-x gdb` adding `-p <pid>` to the suggested command line.
5. In gdb add some break point in the package to be loaded. This will be marked as "pending".
6. In gdb `continue` the R process.
7. In R load the package with `devtools::load_all()`.
8. In R call a function that will reach the break point.
9. In gdb you now have the normal interface but with the Source code being displayed in another buffer. Typically it takes one `next` step for the source buffer to show.

Here a screen shoot showing the `*R*` and `*gdb*` buffers together with the source code. Not the break-point indicated by the red dot and the cursor indicating where processing stands:

[image]

If you load the package some other way, e.g. with `library(..., lib.loc = "...")`, you should open the `src` directory of the package in the first step. That way Emacs can find the corresponding source file. I expect that this can be transferred to QtCreator as well.

Comment: THX a lot for giving insight into "neighbour's garden" :-) When I open a source file manually in QtCreator I can set breakpoints too...

Comment: The R FAQ contains a small section about [Debugging R from within Emacs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Debugging-R-from-within-Emacs)