# Get pid (process ID) of R session from within R session (to attach a debugger)

Tags: r, debugging

How can I find out the process ID of the current R session my R code is running in?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, but an answer working on Windows would also be great.

Comment: Worth an answer :-) I need this to attach a debugger to the R session...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a command called `Sys.getpid()` that outputs the session ID directly

```
Sys.getpid()
#[1] 134164
```